# I do not understand why my calculation is not working

Tags: java

I am very new to programming.
This is the carHire class. One out of the two. I have required to develop a GUI based Car Hire Application. So when I make an entry, everything seems to be working fine, but my rental fee is still 0. I can't figure it out.

`public class CarHire {

```
    private String customerName;
    private String licenseNumber;
    private int daysHired;

        CarHire(){
            customerName=null;
            licenseNumber=null;
            daysHired=0;
            }
        CarHire(String customerName, String licenseNumber, int daysHired){
            this.customerName = customerName;
            this.licenseNumber = licenseNumber;
            this.daysHired = daysHired;
            }
            public void setCustomerName(String customerName){
                this.customerName = customerName;
            }
            public void setLicenseNumber(String licenseNumber){
                this.licenseNumber = licenseNumber;
            }
            public void setDaysHired(int daysHired){
                this.daysHired = daysHired;
            }

            public String getCustomerName()
            {
                return customerName;
            }
            public String getLicenseNumber()
            {
                return licenseNumber;
            }
            public int getDaysHired()
            {
                return daysHired;
            }

    public double calculateHireRental(){
        final double BASE_RATE = 34.5;
    final double NEXT_TIER_RATE = 30.5;
    final double LAST_TIER_RATE = 22.5;

    final int NEXT_TIER_START_DAY=4;
    final int LAST_TIER_START_DAY=7;

    double rental= 0.0;
        int days = 0;

    if(days<NEXT_TIER_START_DAY){   
            rental=days*BASE_RATE;
     } 
        else if(days<=LAST_TIER_START_DAY){
            rental=3*BASE_RATE+(days-3)*NEXT_TIER_RATE;
        }
        else{
    rental=3*BASE_RATE+4*NEXT_TIER_RATE+(days-7)*LAST_TIER_RATE;
        }
        return rental;
    }
}`
```

and the following is GUI class.

// process input data

```
            `public void enterData()
            {
          if (nameField.getText().compareTo("") == 0)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You must enter a customer name","XYZ Car Hire App",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }
                if (licenseField.getText().compareTo("") == 0)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You must enter a license number","XYZ Car Hire App",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }
                if (daysField.getText().compareTo("") == 0)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You must enter days hired","XYZ Car Hire App",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }
                //if (currentCustomer == MAX_NUM)


                                String customerName = nameField.getText();
                                String licenseNumber = licenseField.getText();
                                int daysHired = Integer.parseInt(daysField.getText());

                                displayHeading();
                                CarHire g = new CarHire(customerName,licenseNumber,daysHired);

                    carHireArray[currentCustomer] = g;

                    textArea.append(String.format("%-25s%-28s%-32s$%3.2f\n",customerName, licenseNumber, daysHired, g.calculateHireRental()));






            if (enterButton.isEnabled())//todo-- clear textfields and return focus
                {
                                nameField.setText("");
                nameField.requestFocus();

                licenseField.setText("");
                licenseField.requestFocus();

                daysField.setText("");
                daysField.requestFocus();

        }
                currentCustomer++;//todo-- incremental current cusomer number
        }     
        // Display all bookings
    public void displayAll()
    {
                textArea.setText("");

                displayHeading();
           //todo-- call displayHeading() method
                for(int i=0;i<MAX_NUM;i++)
        {
            CarHire listCustomer = carHireArray[i];

                        textArea.append(String.format("%-25s%-22s%-28s$%3.2f\n",listCustomer.getCustomerName(), listCustomer.getLicenseNumber(), listCustomer.getDaysHired(), listCustomer.calculateHireRental()));
        }//todo-- display all entries entered so far (need using a loop)
                            //todo-- display number of entries, average days hired, total rental
                    if (nameField.getText().compareTo("") == 0)
                    {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No customer entered","XYZ Car Hire App",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }//todo-- complete error message

    }`
```

Comment: Are you asking why calling the `calculateHireRental()` method in your first class sets `rental` to `0.0` and therefore returns `0.0`? If yes, what should it have been instead? Because `if(days<NEXT_TIER_START_DAY){` is truthy, so it will go into that if. And set `rental=days*BASE_RATE;`. But since `days` is `0`, it will do `rental = 0*34.5 = 0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `calculateHireRental()` you have `int days = 0;`, so the first `if` is true and you return `days * BASE_RATE` which is `0`.

Delete the `days` variable and use the class member `daysHired` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Would you be able to tell me how I can fix alignment of the element? textArea.setText(String.format("%-23s%-25s%-28s%-26s\n", ~ ~ ~)); textArea.append(String.format("%-23s%-25s%-28s$%3.2f\n", ~ ~ ~); When the entries are displayed, displayed items are not in alignment with displayHeading(), how could I fix it? –

Comment: @SalmanGotzinho I'm not familiar with `JTextArea`. Anyway new question should be posted as new questions with all the relevant data, not in the comments of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you presented: 
In your GUI you assign a result to 'daysHired' variable

```
        int daysHired = Integer.parseInt(daysField.getText());
```

However in your class CarHire, the variable days is already predefined as 0:

```
int days = 0;
```

So no matter what you multiply by 'days' (by 0) - you will always get 0:

```
 rental=days*BASE_RATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are always setting up the days = 0 ...look up

Answer (score 0):

```
public double calculateHireRental(){
    final double BASE_RATE = 34.5;
final double NEXT_TIER_RATE = 30.5;
final double LAST_TIER_RATE = 22.5;

final int NEXT_TIER_START_DAY=4;
final int LAST_TIER_START_DAY=7;

double rental= 0.0;

/*Delete the "int days = 0;" variable and use the class member "daysHired" instead*/

if(daysHired<NEXT_TIER_START_DAY){   
        rental=daysHired*BASE_RATE;
 } 
    else if(daysHired<=LAST_TIER_START_DAY){
        rental=3*BASE_RATE+(daysHired-3)*NEXT_TIER_RATE;
    }
    else{
rental=3*BASE_RATE+4*NEXT_TIER_RATE+(daysHired-7)*LAST_TIER_RATE;
    }
    return rental;
}
```

try this...

Comment: thanks. works smoothly, now. I always tend to confuse things like this.

Comment: Thank you all. Would you be able to tell me how I can fix alignment of the element? textArea.setText(String.format("%-23s%-25s%-28s%-26s\n", ~ ~ ~)); textArea.append(String.format("%-23s%-25s%-28s$%3.2f\n", ~ ~ ~); When the entries are displayed, displayed items are not in alignment with displayHeading(), how could I fix it?